# MySQL/NODEJS INSERT variable starting with a number

Tags: mysql

From an API i need to save this variable `item.preview_urls.3d_viewer`

But why i get invalid syntax with that? I think thats the "3" in the name... thats showing pink color in my sublime text but how can i use that variable from the api?

Thats the REPLACE INTO (INSERT) for my table

```
REPLACE INTO `item` (item_preview_3D) VALUES ('+ pool.escape(item.preview_urls.3d_viewer) + ')'
```

Its in Javascript (js)

But i get everytime invalid syntax, cause i think there is a "3" in the variable name
How can i get it run? 
I dont have access to the api i call

The error

```
pool.query('REPLACE INTO `item` (item_preview_3D) VALUES ('+ pool.escape(item.preview_urls.3d_viewer) + ')', function(ee, rr) {});


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The code works with other api variables, thats only this 3d_viewer
The sql Table is only item_preview_3D with VARCHAR(255)

I get this error when starting the node! Not when executing the query!

Comment: please share the exact error

Comment: You are using replace query here , what values is being replaced by your variable "pool.escape(item.preview_urls.3d_viewer)" . And what is table structure of item

Comment: the escape doesnt change anything. if i dont use pool.escape, the exact same error comes... I posted the complete error.

Comment: If possible, can you show us the full raw query, after you have concatenated everything?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i cannot run the query, its already getting that error when starting it and not when executing the sql but the api gives back an url. I tested with other api points, the code works... thats only this "3d_viewer" but i dont know why the "3" makes this errors

Comment: `'REPLACE INTO item (item_preview_3D) VALUES ('+ pool.escape(item.preview_urls.3d_viewer) + ')', function(ee, rr) {})` <-- paste the output from this in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no output or something cause the error comes not from executing the SQL query... it already comes when starting the nodejs. I cannot start the node, than i get this invalid error

Comment: Then comment out the call to `pool.query`, and print out the concatenated query.  Seeing the query you are running might help to get you an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried, also not working. Only with console.log i get also the same error and its also pink highlighted... Looks like nodejs doesnt accept variables starting with number or something